# Is CreateDXGIFactory always create the newest version of IDXGIFactory system support?

Tags: directx, directx-11, direct3d11, dxgi

I use CreateDXGIFactory to create a IDXGIFactory(the oldest version), and then use this IDXGIFactory to query IDXGIFactory6, it succeed.(My system version is Win10 1803).

1.So, is this fuction CreateDXGIFactory always create the newest version of IDXGIFactory which the system support?

The similar thing, D3D11CreateDevice create the base version of ID3D11Device, and I can query the ID3D11Device3 successfully?

2.The second question, is fuction D3D11CreateDevice create the newest version of ID3D11Device which the system support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`D3D11CreateDevice` is simpler because it is a single entry point. The documentation does not operate with terms "older version" and "newer version". Instead it suggests that API creates an object with requested interface, and which is adequate to the system you are on and to requested creation arguments (feature level and such). Following that you can obtain access to newer features, when available, by querying newer interfaces, which documentation suggests as well:

> To create a Direct3D 11.1 device (ID3D11Device1), which is available on Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, and Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 with the Platform Update for Windows 7 installed, you first create a ID3D11Device with this function, and then call the QueryInterface method on the ID3D11Device object to obtain the ID3D11Device1 interface.
>
> To create a Direct3D 11.2 device (ID3D11Device2), which is available on Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2, you first create a ID3D11Device with this function, and then call the QueryInterface method on the ID3D11Device object to obtain the ID3D11Device2 interface.

That is, you start creating device the same way and then you query new interfaces. Implementation may or may not respond by stepping up to "newer implementation" depending on whether you ever queried those new interfaces. Either way it remains implementation specific, including that such behavior can technically be changed as long as it transparent to applications consuming the API in this documented way.

With DXGI there are two API entry points `CreateDXGIFactory` and `CreateDXGIFactory1`. The documentation suggests that you don't mix API consumption via 1.0 and 1.1 interfaces.

> Do not mix the use of DXGI 1.0 (IDXGIFactory) and DXGI 1.1 (IDXGIFactory1) in an application. Use IDXGIFactory or IDXGIFactory1, but not both in an application.

This does not necessarily mean that the two functions are creating different factories. Microsoft reserves the right to adjust the behavior as long as you abide by documented guidelines.

If you are not going to do anything that goes beyond DGXI 1.0 you can use `CreateDXGIFactory` on older and newer systems. If you need features of 1.1 and above you are supposed to start with `CreateDXGIFactory1`. Also note that the two functions have different availability across environments and this is one of the reasons they two exist in first place.

Comment: I use CreateDXGIFactory1 to create a IDXGIFactory, and now I can use this IDXGIFactory to get IDXGIFactory6 successfully. I want to know why? is it because my system support DXGI1.6?

Comment: Availability of `IDXGIFactory6` suggests that the system overall supports DGXI 1.6 (earlier systems are unaware of this interface). However there is nothing wrong in available `IDXGIFactory` either because, for starters, `IDXGIFactory1` derives from `IDXGIFactory` and so that the methods of the latter implemented as well.

Comment: no,no,no.I am talking about that I create a IDXGIFactory but not a IDXGIFactory6, but I can get the IDXGIFactory6 from IDXGIFactory.So I think may be the CreateDXGIFactory just create the IDXGIFactory6 for me.

Comment: Important is whether you use `CreateDXGIFactory` or `CreateDXGIFactory1` and not whether you operate with `IDXGIFactory` or `IDXGIFactory1`.

Comment: but I had try CreateDXGIFactory1, CreateDXGIFactory2 before, it gave me the same result.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, the implementation is aligned across variants. It does not need to be the case in older versions of Windows though. You should not get surprised that `CreateDXGIFactory` has `IDXGIFactory6`. This does not violate any documented behavior. DXGI developers could have their reasons to merge the functionality on their side. Their goal is to have correct behavior for 1.0 and 1.1+ apps that consume API in the documented way.

Comment: generally speaking you should always prefer the use of ``CreateDXGIFactory1`` over ``CreateDXGIFactory`` for DirectX 11 applications. That said, most of the problems here were back in the Windows Vista days. Use of ``CreateDXGIFactory2`` is better for debugging, but is problematic if you care about Windows 7 without KB2670838 compatibility. For Direct3D 12 minimum required, it's fine to just use ``CreateDXGIFactory2`` . See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/07/27/dxgi-debug-device/)